# python: compare equality of N dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, compare

I have a list of dfs where some share a common column 'b' value. I group these dfs by their 'b' value, and then want to compare the rest of the columns for any differences. I need to visually output the columns that are different (rather than just identify which column/rows are different which I know you can do with pandas.testing assert_frame_equal). So far, I do this by pre-specifying how many comparisons to run, based on the number of dfs stored in the list (shown in the third section below). But I would like to do it without having to specify the number of dfs to compare, in case there are more another time.

Alternative methods to compare could be .isin (with ~ so it not in?) or an anti merge which i am looking at rn.

all comments are very welcome. thanks so much!

**data**

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 2, 3], 'a': [1,2,3], 'b': ['t1','t1','t1']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 2, 4], 'a': [2,2,4], 'b': ['t1','t1','t1']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 2, 3], 'a': [1,2,3], 'b': ['t2','t2','t2']})
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 2, 3], 'a': [1,2,3], 'b': ['t3','t3','t3']})
df5 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 2, 3], 'a': [1,2,3], 'b': ['t1','t1','t1']})

df_lst=[df1,df2,df3,df4,df5]
```

**split in to lists according to group in column 'b'**

```
from itertools import groupby

out = []
for _, g in groupby(
    sorted(df_lst, key=lambda k: k["b"].tolist()), lambda k: k["b"].tolist()):
    out.append(list(g))
```

**compare each df stored in the list (of lists) of dfs in 'out'**

```
for i in out:
    if len(i) > 1:
        a = (i[0].compare(i[1]))
        b = (i[0].compare(i[2]))
        c = (i[1].compare(i[2]))
lst=(a,b,c)
pd.concat(lst)
```

**perhaps something like this** but this only compares 0 to all other dfs so does not work

```
for i in out:
    if len(i)>1:
        for j in range(len(i)):
            a = i[0].compare(i[j])
            o.append(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should compare every entry of `out` with every other entry:

```
if all(isinstance(x, list) for x in out):
    out_df = []
    for entry in out:
        out_df.append(pd.DataFrame(entry))
    out = out_df

comp_list = []
for i, entry_1 in enumerate(out):
    for j, entry_2 in enumerate(out):
        if j > i:
            comp = (entry_1.compare(entry_2))
            comp_list.append(comp)

lst = tuple(comp_list)
pd.concat(lst)
```

---

*Edit*: I have added the `if` statement at the beginning of the snippet to account for cases where `out` stores lists and not dataframes (as is the case in your original example after the split).

Comment: hi @georgykoshteyn. Thanks for your input. however this throws an AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'compare' error which I'm not sure why

Comment: @br101 The error occurs, since `out` is not a list of dataframes but a list of lists. That is, when you split the data, you are applying `list()` to `g` before appending `g` to `out`. `compare()`, however, is a method of dataframes - lists do not have such a method. To resolve this, you could transform the entries of `out` to dataframes (respectively not apply `list()` during the splitting process in the first place). I've updated my answer to account for this scenario. Let me know whether it works for you.